# Copying and pasting selected rows in Excel individually to Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy, paste

Seeking help and would appreciate anything that can come my way!
Stackoverflow has been a huge help for my research so far.

- I am trying to copy and paste SELECTED rows from Excel to Word
- If B2, B4, B10 is selected, data between F2:N2; F4:N4 and F10:N10 will be copied and pasted into word
- PROBLEM now is that only the row B2 is copy and pasted three times over
- I want to use LOOP because I want to maintain separate formatting for each row pasted

Many thanks!

```
Sub createwordreporttest1()

Dim c As Range
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Set wordapp = New Word.Application
Dim cl As Range
Dim r As Long
Set cl = Selection
r = cl.Row
Dim cl1 As Range
Set selectedrng = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)

With wordapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
    
    With .Selection
    For Each c In Selection
        Range("F" & r, Range("N" & r)).Copy
        .PasteExcelTable True, True, True
    Next
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Currently you aren't altering the value of `r` and therefore the row of the first selected cell is being copied each time. If you are only selecting single cells from different rows (e.g. B2, B4, B10) then you could use the following line instead `Range("F" & c.Row, Range("N" & c.Row)).Copy`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this suggestion. That suggestion works, but it seems to work only some of the time. I now sometimes get an empty error message half way or a quarter way through the pasting. Would someone be able to provide suggestions?

Comment: Hi - I've debugged it and got an error
"Run-time error '4605'
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: What line did you get the error? Also, do you really need the pasted table data to be linked to the original Excel file or are you happy for the data to be pasted into Word and not be connected to the original Excel file after that?

Comment: Hi Sam, it doesn't highlight the line. But I finally found the solution anyways - it is actually a problem with Excel's copy and paste clipboard. All I need to do is delay the code by one second before copying. It seems to be a well documented issue. Thanks again and you've been a big help!